# What could be the cause of this NullPointer Exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The following is a part of my code.

I get a NullPointerException in the line " buckets[i][h.hashBands(sum, bandRows)].add(j); ".

What could be the reason?

```
public static void generateBuckets()
{
    hash h = new hash();
    buckets = new ArrayList[bands][bandRows];

     for(int i=0; i<bands; i++)
     {
         for(int j=0; j<preprocessedList.size(); j++)
         {
             int[] sum = new int[bandRows];
             int a=0;
             for(int k=i; k<bands; k++)
             {
                 sum [a] = sigMatrix[k][j];
                 a++;
             }
             buckets[i][h.hashBands(sum, bandRows)].add(j);
         }
     }
```

The h.hashBands() function is as follows

```
public int hashBands(int[] in, int bucketSize) 
    {        
        BigInteger hashVal = BigInteger.ZERO;
        int k = in.length;
        BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
        BigInteger size = BigInteger.valueOf(bucketSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
            hashVal = (hashVal.add(BigInteger.valueOf(in[i]).multiply(base.pow(k-i-1))));

        hashVal = hashVal.mod(size);
        return hashVal.intValue();
    }
```

Comment: `buckets[i][h.hashBands(sum, bandRows)]` is null perhaps? How do you initialize this array?

Comment: I've initialize it as buckets = new ArrayList[bands][bandRows];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a 2D array of ArrayLists

```
buckets = new ArrayList[bands][bandRows];
```

but never filling it with ArrayLists so every element is null.  When you call .add(), you get a NullPointerExcepion

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `buckets[][]`.
You will need to add a `buckets = new BucketType[xlength][ylength];` somewhere before using it.

Comment: No that's initialized already in my class as buckets = new ArrayList[bands][bandRows];

Comment: Yeah, that won't help.  You have to initialise the actual entry in it that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised that particular entry in the `buckets` array to anything.

Answer (score 0):

very hard to say for sure.
either you haven't initialized buckets, or the elements in it, ...
anyway, answering this for sure is pretty impossible.
it would be easier if we saw a bit more of the code, and maybe the stacktrace.